# NameError: name 'warehouse_initial_quantity_aircondSec' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nameerror

[image]

remaining code:

```
if id_parts == "EBS04":
            piston_quantity_warehouse = warehouse_initial_quantity_aircondSec + order_from_supplier
            return piston_quantity_warehouse
        elif id_parts == "BWBS03":
            door_quantity_warehouse = warehouse_initial_quantity_bodyworkSec  + order_from_supplier
            return door_quantity_warehouse
        else:
            print("No such id")
    else:
        print("Wrong supplier")
else:
    print("Wrong supplier")
print(warehouseUpdateSupplier)

updateBiosWarehouseInventory()
```

Input:

```
Enter Supplier name: tab
The id of the part: abs01
How many orders from supplier: 2
```

Output:

```
NameError: name 'warehouse_initial_quantity_aircondSec' is not defined
```

Can anyone help me with this >< Been spending hours on it :\ Thank You so much

Comment: `warehouse_initial_quantity_aircondSec` is just a local variale from the ogher method

Answer (score 1):

The variable `warehouse_initial_quantity_aircondSec` is local to the method `initial_quantity()`, you're calling it, but that doesn't give you the variable you have to store it. The name may be different

```
def initial_quantity():
    warehouse_initial_quantity_aircondSec = 1000
    return warehouse_initial_quantity_aircondSec


def updateBiosWarehouseInventory():
    warehouse_initial_quantity_aircondSec  = initial_quantity()
    ...
```

You can even do

```
def initial_quantity():
    return 1000
```